# How does cvHaarDetectObjects work?

Tags: c++, opencv, face-detection

I'm trying to learn how cvHaarDetectObjects works... 
I couldn't visualize how it's working... how Integral image calculated and finding a face...

We put a rectangle on the face area... How do we find this area?

```
if (faces)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < faces->total; ++i)
    {
        CvPoint point1, point2;
        CvRect* rectangle = (CvRect*)cvGetSeqElem(faces, i);
        point1.x = rectangle->x;
        point2.x = (rectangle->x + rectangle->width);
        point1.y = rectangle->y;
        point2.y = (rectangle->y + rectangle->height);
        cvRectangle(frame, point1, point2, CV_RGB(255,0,0));...
```

Answer (score 2):

Read this wiki page,
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viola%E2%80%93Jones_object_detection_framework

There is a famous algorithm called Viola Jones method:
http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/viola/Pubs/Detect/violaJones_CVPR2001.pdf

Hope it will help you understand how this works.

Answer (score 0):

A rectangle is made up in OpenCV library by having two corners, SO

```
point1.x = rectangle->x;
point2.x = (rectangle->x + rectangle->width);
point1.y = rectangle->y;
point2.y = (rectangle->y + rectangle->height);
```

from

```
CvRect* rectangle = (CvRect*)cvGetSeqElem(faces, i);
```

gets where is detecting a face, it uses those x and y coordenates, makes up the two needed pints with them (code above) and then, draws the rectangle with the points as arguments:

```
cvRectangle(frame, point1, point2, CV_RGB(255,0,0));
```

Comment: That's only about the rectangle. The "face" is recognized means the haar file in xml which includes several annotations (features of a face, distances, shapes) so it can find a face in an image (still image, video frame, etc).